# How to change the date format across the entire system

Tags: wingpanel, pantheon-files, time

It seems that similar questions are being buried for what ever reason.

I want to change the date format across the entire system (Files, Wingpanel, etc...) to a format of my own choice (YYYY.MM.DD hh:mm:ss). How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible to enforce one custom date-time format on every thing unfortunately.  If you search for "format" with dconf-editor you will find 8 or 9 different settings for different apps that control date and/or time format they use and most of those do not provide for an arbitrary custom format. For example for the wingpanel the time can be '12h', '24h' or 'ISO'.  In the 'Language and Region' plug in Switchboard you can use the "Format" selector to choose a set of pre-set formats suitable for different locales but no customization.  It is not part of elementary philosophy to cater for much customization, which may not please some users.